# 2 nics each with static IP addresses - how to tell only one to accept inbound

Tags: networking, iptables, mint, nic

I have 2 nics on my motherboard in a Linux Mint 18 box.

I have setup static ip addresses for each nic (100 and 101).

I want to address the box by a single hostname from remote machines (which means using one IP address), but it seems the inbound traffic to the Mint box is only accepted on one or other of the 100 or 101 IP addresses, and it seems to (possibly) change across restarts.

Is there a way to configure one NIC for inbound traffic and one for outbound traffic?

Or should I just use 1 of the NICS as there's little or no advantage to having them both plugged in at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to configure one NIC for inbound traffic and one for outbound traffic?

You can do this using iptables and targeting the interfaces themself like so:

First allow all traffic by default:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Now lets say `eth0` should accept only incomming traffic:

```
iptables -p OUTPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -p FORWARD -i eth0 -j DROP
```

And now say `eth1` should only allow outgoing traffic:

```
iptables -p INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
iptables -p FORWARD -i eth1 -j DROP
```